# Scheduling shell script in crontab

Tags: linux, shell, debian, cron

I have a shell script that I can run with `root` user this way:

`root@vivid-15:~# ./backup.sh`

It's on `/root/backup.sh`. Now, how do I schedule it on `crontab` to execute every day at 01:00 AM? I done this:

`0 1 * * * root`

But now I don't know how to proceed the command to do that.

Comment: Are you using your own crontab or /etc/crontab?

Comment: If you're wondering how to get there, `crontab -e` is the easiest way for debian/ubuntu.

Comment: @kevlar1818 Nice, but I used `vim` instead. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @robert I used `/etc/crontab`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown `crontab -e` will edit the file with whatever your default editor is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?  Also, a "1" in the hour field means 1am, not 1pm.

```
0 1 * * * root /root/backup.sh
```

Edit: changed the 13 (1pm) back to 1 (1am).

Answer (score 2):

Crontab format:

```
MIN HOUR DAY MON WEEKDAY CMD
```

I don't know that you need to define what user you want it to run as when its in crontab -- commands will be run as the user who makes the entries with crontab -e.  To create a cron process that runs as root, either login as root or set it up with $ sudo crontab -e

I think you're looking for something more like this:

```
0 1 * * * /root/backup.sh
```

Comment: You forgot the user before the script call.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: System crontabs require the username field; user crontabs don't. `man 5 crontab` for details.

Comment: I using `/etc/crontab`. I forgot to specify that on question. +1 for ya